# How can I select GTAV in Visual Studio Graphic Debugger applications?

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, directx, visual-studio-2017, direct3d

I am using Visual Studio Graphics Debugger in VS2017 and only shows MS apps. I even selected it in the edit and added it and GTAV is in running state but can't be selected:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: (Regarding Gareth's answer):
I already showed my directX control panel, there's nothing further I could do:
[image]
Also, in `other debug options`, after clicking, it shows the same thing as the first window:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the limitation is not related to the debug targets all being MS, as Candy Crush is by King.

What they do seem to have in common is that they've all been installed the same way, probably through the Windows Store as App Packages, while GTA was installed with an executable installer.

Consider looking in the "Other Debug Targets" or "Attach to Process" menus for attaching to non-App Packages. The DirectX Control Panel menu item may also be worth reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

*Debug Installed App Package* only works on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. GTA V is a Win32 desktop app, so it would not be expected to show up in that menu.

You can run VSGS on a EXE by opening it with Visual Studio, and then using *Debug* / *Graphics* -> *Start Graphics Debuggi*ng. It's quite common, however, for Win32 desktop applications to use 'ripple' launchers, so the EXE you start isn't actually the Direct3D game EXE.

Applications are also free to request that Visual Studio not support capturing them via an API, which is possible here as well. This is done via the `D3DPerf_SetOptions(1)` method, use of the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_PREVENT_ALTERING_LAYER_SETTINGS_FROM_REGISTRY` flag, or by reacting to the value returned from `IsAnnotationEnabled:GetStatus` or `ID3D11DeviceContext2::IsAnnotationEnabled`.

Comment: Just adding a note, I have Installed GTAV in x64 mode. I did that but gave an error. I consulted with the person who wrote the tutorial, and was told possibly the Rockstar has designed the exe to exit when being debugged. I am not sure. It gave the error: it took long to run and says something about remote debugger. I will add more info tomorrow. The tutorial author said something like your last paragraph that possibly GTAV doesn't allow debugging but I can use renderdoc to access each frame information from GPU which is weird why I can't do the same here.